# Query not working like it is supposed to

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get this query to work

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE test2(IN tbl CHAR(64), IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl );
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

This is the code used to call it

```
CALL test2(groups,NAME)
```

And this is the error I get: 
1 Unknown column 'groups' in 'field list' SQL2.sql 1 12

The table name is groups, and the column name is NAME - Why is this not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have written a stored procedure that takes character strings, and you have passed identifiers.

Try calling it thusly:

```
CALL test2('groups', 'NAME')
```